# How to make a tooltip for when a user hovers over a checkbox? (Material Design Lite)

Tags: html, css, material-design

This is what I'm trying right now that isn't working. Trying to get the tooltip to show when the user hovers over the checkbox.

```
 <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="Asia">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Asia" class="mdl-checkbox__input">
            <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Asia</span>
    </label>
    <div class="mdl-tooltip" for="Asia">
            -China<br>-Hong Kong<br>-Japan<br>-Korea<br>-Philippines<br>-Singapore<br>-Taiwan<br>-Vietnam
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a data attribute such as data-tooltip or whatever you like to call it. Add your text to the attribute.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-my-tooltip="Hello World">
```

CSS:

```
[data-my-tooltip]:before {
    content: attr(data-my-tooltip);
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;

}

[data-my-tooltip]:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 3px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    margin: -25px 0 0 0;   /*setting it above. to the left. You can play with this */
}
```

Comment: just to make life easier, what would I do to margin to move the tooltip to the right?

Comment: margin right is the second place. This is the order for margin: top right bottom left; So go ahead and play with those numbers till you find the position you like.